# how to display several images with keras?

Tags: python, image, keras

how to show many images stored in a list using keras image
the below code show only the first image while the list contains several images

```
for errimg in anomalylist:
  print (errimg)  
  showimg = image.load_img(errimg, target_size=(224, 224))
  plt.imshow(showimg)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for errimg in anomalylist:
  print (errimg)  
  showimg = image.load_img(errimg, target_size=(224, 224))
  plt.imshow(showimg)   
  plt.show()
```